# Viewing GLOBALS programatically using ObjectScript or VisM

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I am tasked with getting the list of all the NODES in Global Data, specifically,
all data that looks like `^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY",,,)` :

```
1:  ^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY",1,63543,5870)  =   ""
2:  ^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY",1,63572,9792)  =   ""
3:  ^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY",1,63573,9904)  =   ""
4:  ^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY",1,63650,20950) =   ""
5:  ^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY",1,63651,21058) =   ""
```

I only need the ***nodes***, not the *values* itself. Is there a way to get this list programatically? 
I have tried exporting the whole xml of the globals via this code in VB.net with the VisM control :

`AxVisM1.Code = "do $system.OBJ.Export(""BACKTR.GBL"",""C:\Users\Support\Desktop\global.xml"")"`

however, this creates a xml file that includes all the nodes under BACKTR. I only need nodes that are like `^BACKTR("INDX", "COMPANY",,,)`

Is there an objectscript syntax I can use to output that list? Or should I resort to using XML? I just need the object script syntax for it, as I can execute code in VisM anyway

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to export just any part of data in a global, like you want. You can just [merge](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_cmerge), any data to any empty global, and export it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run two object script codes?
(copy to a temp global then export)

```
merge ^BACKTRTMP=^BACKTR("INDX","COMPANY")
do $system.OBJ.Export("BACKTRTMP.GBL","C:\Users\Support\Desktop\global.xml")
```

you can then dispose of the temp global later

```
kill ^BACKTRTMP
```